# How to iterate an unknown length list in one column into another sheet's column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
    function Name_Iterate() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var UpdateSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Update");
      var nameSheet = ss.getSheetByName("New Names");
      var names = nameSheet.getRange(2, 1,(nameSheet.getLastRow()-1),1).getValues()

      var names_transpose=[0]

      for (var i = 0; i<names.length; i++){

      names_transpose.push(names[i][0])  

      }

      Logger.log(names_transpose)
      Logger.log(names)
      //Now get last row in update tab

  for (var NameAmount=0; NameAmount<(UpdateSheet.getLastRow()-1)/names.length; NameAmount++){ 

    UpdateSheet.getRange(2+names.length*NameAmount,2,nameSheet.getLastRow()-1,2).setValues([names_transpose])

    //Devisor=length of LDAP array
    //Lead amount % 

  }
  }
```

Here is the link to my spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmGydysjK0-rdHZkSGk3UFkydzVBcEJIY2hjU01kU1E#gid=0

I am trying to iterate the names placed in the 'New Names' tab into the second column of the 'Update' tab until the first instance of an empty row. I'm running into problems, however, with the setValues commmand and also the logic of how (by group? one at a time?) to put these new names into the other sheet.

Here's the error I get when running as-is: "Incorrect range height, was 1 but should be 8 (line 21, file "Code")"

and when i change line 21 to:

```
UpdateSheet.getRange(2+names.length*NameAmount,2,nameSheet.getLastRow()-1,2).setValues(names)
```

I get the error: "Incorrect range width, was 1 but should be 2 (line 21, file "Code")"

I think its due to the array form of my 'names' list when I need it in a list style column rather than rows. Any ideas?

Comment: Note: this code is [google-apps-script]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would be several ways of approaching the logic, but in answer to:

> the setValues commmand and also the logic of how (by group? one at a
>   time?) to put these new names into the other sheet.

always try to perform read and write operations to the spreadsheet in as big a batch as possible. In other words, use Javascript to build your array, and set it in one go.

One way of approaching it (not sure if this is the most efficient):

```
function Name_Iterate2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var UpdateSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Update");
  var nameSheet = ss.getSheetByName("New Names");
  var names = nameSheet.getRange(2, 1,(nameSheet.getLastRow()-1),1).getValues();
  var reqLength = UpdateSheet.getLastRow() - 1;
  while (names.length < reqLength) names = names.concat(names);
  var output = names.slice(0, reqLength);
  UpdateSheet.getRange(2, 2, reqLength, 1).setValues(output);    
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean about batch processes. This works perfectly. Thank you